# How do i make my server run and receive messages in real time with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can create a NodeJS Server, but it looks like it is not receiving messages in real time. I have a device that will send messages to this server im creating over the time, and i just want to ''console.log'' the response every time it receives it. It is that simple.
That said, is important to notice that **I DO NOT have control over the server sending me the data**. I haven't created it and i can't touch it. It is external. But i do know that it's sending the data to my server, i just don't know how to receive it in real time....

My code right now is this one. Feel free to change it and completely rework it if you want, im not very experienced in NodeJS. Also feel free to use any other library, as i have tried doing so using many others with no success.

```
import http from 'http';

const host = 'MY.IP';
const port = 0000;

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("--SERVER ONLINE.");
};

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

**EDIT**: I believe i have failed to explain properly: What I need is to PRINT the data im receiving from the OTHER SERVER in the one from the code above.
Code above creates *server A*.
*server A* is receiving data from *server B*.
I need to *print* the data *server B* sent on *server A*.
Server B is sending the data via HTTP POST request.

**EDIT2**: I have changed my code, and im getting close to doing what i need,but still, no sucess. Now i have:

```
import http from 'http';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const httpServer = http.createServer();


httpServer.on('request', (request, response) => {
    if (request.url == '/')
        response.end('Server online!');
        console.log(request);
});

httpServer.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running at ${PORT}`));
```

Everytime there is a request for the server it does indeed, print the request on my screen. I can see that *server B* is sending the data to this server i created, working fine and the data is 100% being sent. I just need to "console.log" the data im receiving now. Still no success.

Comment: And whats the problem? Have you tried it with a browser or postman? What do you mean with "real time" Your code should work. If you hit  the server with a http request, you sould receive "--SERVER ONLINE."

Comment: Yes,it works, but i believe i failed to explain properly. I want to print the data i'm receiving from the OTHER Server. Let's say, my server on the code above is server A, and it is receiving data from server B. I want to print the data SERVER A is receiving in real-time from SERVER B (on server A).

Comment: How is server B sending data? Via HTTP Post request? Via HTTP Put request. Using plain TCP socket? Via XMPP? There's not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Via HTTP Post Request. I will update my question. I completely forgot about this,

Comment: @Master Why do you need server B? Just have a webpage do a AJAX post request to get the data and then console.log it

Comment: Because its a 3rd party device that i have no control of, need 100% to use it, and i can't touch it. I need a server that will listen to it 24/7,and not only get the data once.

Comment: "*it looks like it is not receiving messages in real time.*" - what makes it look like that? Are you saying the messages are delayed? Or are you not receiving any messages at all? It's not quite clear what the problem is.

Comment: The problem was that it was not receiving messages at all. The question is already solved. I have solved it and posted the answer here. No need to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for requests sent to your server by using `<httpserver>.on('request', callback)`

Try something like this

```
import http from 'http';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const httpServer = http.createServer();


httpServer.on('request', (request, response) => {
    if (request.url == '/')
        response.end('reached server!');
});

httpServer.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`running on port ${PORT}`));
```

In this example, by going to `http://localhost:3000/` it should show "reached server!"

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer. The code does indeed work, but the problem is, what i need to do now is print the message this server you created is receiveing. So let's say the code you posted is server A, and server B is sending data. I would like to echo the data from server B on server B now

Comment: @Master but if server B is making a http POST request, then all i can do is send back a response object (or message), and its upto the owner of server B to handle that message and do whatever he wants to with it

Comment: There is no way for me to get the data sent with HTTP POST on server A?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by myself. Took me almost 2 days, as i have no prior experience in NodeJS, but here is the answer. I hope it helps someone in the future:

```
import http from 'http';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const httpServer = http.createServer();


httpServer.on('request', (request, response) => {
    if (request.url == '/')
        response.end('Server online!');
request.on('data',function(data){
         console.log(data.toString());
});
      });



httpServer.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running at: ${PORT}`));
```

The part i was missing was this one:

```
request.on('data',function(data){
             console.log(data.toString());
    });
```

I didn't knew i could use a 'on' event on a 'request',because 'request' is already an event by itself. But i could, and this solves my problem.

Now **server A** is receiving and printing every message from **server B** in real time, and i can do whatever i want with the response!